# Stop refreshing a specific div when browsing

Tags: html, persistent, audio-player

I'm working on my website where I have a music player. The annoying part is that when I browse to another page the player stops and starts from begining...
What I want is to have a persistent music player. So how can I make the div that contains the music player to be static when browsing to another page? 
The website: demo(dot)zdringhi-art(dot)com

Thanks!

Comment: Stop playing music without specific user action! **Seriously!**

Answer (score 1):

WEB is stateless.
So if you move to another page there is no way for a div to remain the same.

Although what you can do is that... Hmm as follows.
Have a single page and have your div in there.
Then the other part of the page is loaded via ajax.
also when a link is clicked only parts of pages will be loaded.
Seems too much of coding , but is the only feasible option.
For eg take facebook

Answer (score 1):

Gurav shah is correct, the web is stateless so if you are changing pages you only have a few options for this.

Frames, yes before anyone shouts this is what they were designed for. You could have the music player in one HTML frame and the rest of the page in another so when you move around you are only updating the main content frame.

Or do as gurav suggests and make your whole site one page and update the content with Ajax, so the music Div does not change.

Pass the current position of the player to the next page when you click a link.

```
     <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='{new page}?musicpositionseconds="+getsecond()+"'; return false">to another page</a>
```

Where getseconds() returns the current position of the music player and passes it to the next page then when that page is loaded you read in the variable from the URL and start the player from there.

Comment: Hmm...I understand. So the easy way is to use frames.
I just found that some players have the "autoresume" option, but when I tried on my player doesn't work.

Comment: It would depend on the player and how the autoresume works. Most players autoresume only works when coming back to the same page, if the URL is different then that could be why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Using frames is one solution but since you are using JQuery on your site you should check out `.load` (http://api.jquery.com/load/). It allows you to load the content of another page and put it somewhere in the current page. Something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    $("#ja-container").load($(this).attr("href") + " #ja-container");
    /* Load the new page using ajax request, take the content in #ja-container from that new page and put it in the current page's #ja-container */
  });
});
```

This is not a complete solution: when someone clicks Concerts -> Agenda you should keep Agenda visible.

Personally, instead of forced background music I'd rather like to see a page with Youtube videos of the people playing the music.

Comment: I know it's annoying the background music, but it's not my idea.
The project is to convert a flash website into a static one (using Joomla! as you can see) and I have converted all the other things except the player and the owner want it to be the same piece by piece :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes HTTP is stateless. what you can do is create a cookie, and update it with current location/time value of the player, constantly. This way, when you go to any other page you can read time/location from cookie.

otherwise, in a cookie less approach, sending AJAXed location/time data back-forth server-client will be too much network.

If I was doing this, I would have gone cookie way.

Comment: yeah, agree with Sinan. if its background music and no way to stop, you are probably causing a lot of pain to your visitors.

Comment: agree with Saini too. I don't want to use frames or iframe on me website whatever the objective is unless there's no other solution.
Well, I'm a newby in java/ajax programming, so can you help me with a link of a tutorial to 'cook' some cookies for my player?
Thanks!